# Why have I been getting Twitter's rate limit error for over 15 minutes?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I literally haven't used my keys and secret tokens in over 12 hours and I still get the `420` error for rate limit. Here's the code.

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_secret = ''

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

data = api.rate_limit_status()

print data['resources']['statuses']['/statuses/home_timeline']
print data['resources']['users']['/users/lookup']
```

and I get the following:

```
{u'reset': 1509916835, u'limit': 15, u'remaining': 15}
{u'reset': 1509916835, u'limit': 900, u'remaining': 900}
420
420
420
```

What happened? Am I banned? I've tried using multiple accounts to no avail...

Comment: Have you tried asking the people operating the servers that you're talking to? Have you tried using a different account? My guess is that this is not actually a programming problem, which would further make it off topic here.

Comment: I've made several other accounts. All of them are getting rate limited.

Comment: Are they getting rate-limited right away? What about the other questions?

Comment: I haven't asked anyone about what is happening and I don't know where I should go for that. I literally just woke up, 10 hours after my last attempt, and I'm still getting the `420` error. Still rate limited. It happens about 5 seconds after execute my script.